# When I am trying to open application designed in spring boot it is throwing 401 unauthorized only in chrome

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

[image]

When I am trying to open application  designed in spring boot it is throwing 401 unauthorized only in chrome. Working in remaining browsers and low versions . It is working application . From last 1 month it stopped working .We are using spring security Oauth2 .

Comment: pls add more code - we will get to know sthg. Is it working in other browsers at present?

Comment: Yes it is working in other browsers

Comment: Add more code pls